# Get column from 2 tables and sort by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have 2 tables both containing an `event` and `date` column. Is there a way to combine the results of both column's `event` field into one and sort them by their `date` field. That way only a single (and combined) `event` is returned instead of 2.

Comment: you have to use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT event,date FROM table1
UNION
SELECT event,date FROM table2 ORDER BY date
```

When using UNION you use ORDER by at bottom query it will order marged query

You can't use it except bottom query anyway it should throw an error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.event, MAX(a.date) date
FROM
        (
           SELECT event, date FROM TableA
           UNION
           SELECT event, date FROM TableB
        ) a
GROUP   BY a.event
ORDER   BY a.date DESC
```